# Excel Pivot Tables - Use same field as row and column label

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

Looking to create a pivot table with the same field for row & column labels.

If this isn't possible in Excel, is there a suitable alternative within excel to accomplish the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Plan B.

Two columns in your source data that are identical, one for ROWS one for COLUMNS.